# Using Python to read all emails from Outlook Folder

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

I would like to read all emails from a specific folder from Outlook, but for some reason, I manage to get only 1 year of data. If I run it today I get all emails from 04-Dec-20 until 04-Dec-19.

Am I doing something wrong in the iteration?

```py
import win32com.client

# create object
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
# get the folder
root_folder = outlook.Folders['myemail@xxxxx.com'].Folders['Folder']


messages = root_folder.Items

subject_content = []
body_content = []
creation_time = []
for message in messages:
    subject_content.append(message.subject)
    body_content.append(message.body)
    creation_time.append(message.creationtime)
    message = messages.GetNext()
```

Comment: Do you get an error? Is that a cached or an online profile in Outlook?

Comment: I get no error, but I would like to fetch many years of data instead of the past year only.

Comment: Again, what kind of a profile is it?

Comment: It's a online profile

Answer (score 0):

In the online profile Exchange server limits the number of simultaneously open messages to 255. To avoid running out of the RPC channels, release items as soon as you are done with them and avoid using "foreach" iterators - they keep all accessed object referenced until the iterator is released. Use a "for" loop instead (`for index in range(1, messages.Count+1)`)